# How to make java method not return anything if result is not correct

Tags: java, methods

Hi everyone, I'm making a java program that will display all perfect numbers in a given range. I have to do this by using method and this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
        String result = isPerfect(i);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

public static String isPerfect(int num){
    String result = "";
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++){
        if ((num % i) == 0){
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    if (sum == num){
        result = "Number " + num + " is a perfect number";
    }else{
        result = "Number " + num + " is not a perfect number";
    }
    return result;
}
```

I expect to get a list consisting only of perfect numbers which for range from 1 to 1000 are 6, 28 and 496.

For the actual result I get these numbers but I also get the line from else part in the method, that is "Number #num is not a perfect number". I tried changing the return method but I couldn't find a solution to this. I put an empty string when the result is not true but then I get my line for perfect number 6 and then everything till the next perfect number is empty line, in this case from 6 and 28 there are 22 empty lines. How can I change this so my method doesn't return anything if the result is not the one that I want?

[pic of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdCu3.png)

So I'd like not to get anything from that pic except for "Number 496 is a perfect number"

Comment: just make `isPerfect` return a `boolean` like it's name suggests. Then in main put `if(isPerfect(i)) { System.out.println("Number " + i + " is a perfect number"); }`

Answer (score 2):

You are really close, there is one thing that I would change and that's returning a `boolean` rather than a `String`. This way the method `isPerfect` will return either true or false, which is kind of logical as it's either a perfect number or its not.

And then from that point you can print the perfect numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
        if(isPerfect(i)){
            System.out.println("Number "+ i + " is a perfect number");
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isPerfect(int num){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++){
        if ((num % i) == 0){
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    if (sum == num){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove println, and in your if do this: `"is a perfect number\n"` 
Then in your else, put empty string. So this if you want to stick to yuor code and dont want to change anything. If you want to modify your code a lot use @Fubars method which is also correct